Rotation number and semiconjugacy.
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Suppose $f,g : S^1 \to S^1$ are two homeomorphisms so that, for some homeomorphism $h: S^1 \to S^1,$ we have $$h \circ f \circ h^{-1} = g$$ That is, $f$ is conjugate to $g$ in the group of circle homeomorphisms.
I want to show that $f$ and $g$ have the same rotation number.
some thoughts:
I believe that my solution should be divided into two cases:
If the rotation number of $f$ denoted by $\tau (f)$ is rational or irrational. In case of
rational number $p/q,$ I know that any periodic point has period $q.$
I am also guessing that this post Rotation number invariant under topological semi-conjugacy. might be helpful to me but I do not know how.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Does conjugacy imply semicinjugacy?

https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2020/REUPapers/Donald.pdf has a proof. I will delineate key points in that proof in my answer for ease of access, I do not claim any originality. Also, semi-conjugacy implies conjugacy.

@UrmiDaniellaAzar on which page is the proof?

Let $\pi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ be the covering map; $F,\ H$ be the corresponding lifts (of $f,\ h$) $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. We also additionally enforce $F(0),H(0)\in[0,1]$. W.l.o.g. we take $F$ to be increasing (i.e. $f$ is orientation-preserving).

Lemma 1: $H^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is actually the lift of $h^{-1}:S^1\rightarrow S^1$. 
Proof: $h^{-1}\circ\pi=h^{-1}\circ\pi\circ H\circ H^{-1} = h^{-1}\circ h\circ \pi\circ H^{-1}=\pi\circ H^{-1}$. $\blacksquare$

We then have, $G:=H\circ F\circ H^{-1}$ is a valid lift of $g$ with $G(0)\in[0,1]$.

Lemma 2: $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have 
$|H(x)-x|\leq 1$
$|H^{-1}(x)-x|\leq 1$
Proof: $h^{-1}$ and $h$ are homeomorphisms, hence degree 1 maps. The claim follows. $\blacksquare$

We need another uniform bound estimate as follows:

Lemma 2: $\forall x,y\in[0,1]$ we have 
$|F^n(x)-F^n(y)|\leq 2\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$
Proof: We take $x<y$ w.l.o.g.  If $F(0)\notin(x,y)$, $\pi$ is a length-preserving homeomorphism from $F^n([x,y])$ to a subset of $S^1$, so, $|F^n(x)-F^n(y)|\leq 1\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$
Otherwise, put $z:= F(0)$, $\pi$ is a length-preserving homeomorphism from $F^n([x,z])$ and $F^n([z,y])$ to subsets of $S^1$. Adding the two lengths and using the triangle-inequality, we get $|F^n(x)-F^n(y)|\leq 2\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ $\blacksquare$

Now, to show that the rotation numbers are equal (from definition), all we have to show is, for appropriate $x\in\mathbb{R}$ ($x=H(0)$ works); $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{|F^n(x)-x|}{n}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{|G^n(x)-x|}{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{|H\circ F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)-x|}{n}}$$
We simply do the following:
$$||F^n(x)-x|-|H\circ F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)-x||\leq |F^n(x)-H\circ F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)|$$
and re-write RHS as follows:
$$|F^n(x)-H\circ F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)|= |F^n(x)-F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)+F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)-H\circ F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)|$$
Now, clearly, we can bound
$$|F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)-H\circ F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)|\leq 1 \ \text{[Lemma 2]}$$
$$|F^n(x)-F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)|\leq 2\ \text{[Lemma 2 and 3]}$$
And, by triangle inequality
$$|F^n(x)-H\circ F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)|\leq 3$$
and, combining these inequalities, we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left\lvert\frac{|F^n(x)-x|}{n}-\frac{|H\circ F^n\circ H^{-1}(x)-x|}{n}\right\rvert}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{3}{n}}=0$$
Note that we needed $h$ only to satisfy Lemma 1 and 2; and we can, even in this proof, relax the conditions a bit. We can also try to relax Lemma 1 with a weaker requirement, if $h$ is only surjective.

I do not understand the proof of lemma 2, could you clarify more details please?

How did you distinguish between rational and irrational rotation numbers in your solution above? What is the case for rational rotation numbers?

Did you used the idea that "2 different irrational rotations can not be conjugate" in your proof?
